# Creating an endless spinner in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a gameobject spinning around its y-axis. This spinner should have a initial movement direction and when colliding with something, it should change its direction.

I created a little picture to show what I mean, but I want the behaviour for a 3D game.

[image]

So I just started with the rotation of the spinner,

```
public class Spinner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float movementSpeed; // speed when moving

    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationSpeed; // speed when rotating

    private Rigidbody rigid;
    private Vector3 movementDirection; // the direction the spinner is moving

    private void Start()
    {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, rotationSpeed, 0); // rotate the spinner around its y-axis
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        // set new direction
    }

}
```

How can I move the spinner, that it moves along a direction and whenever it collides with something, it changes its direction. It should never stop moving or rotating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to point out a few things:

- The Unity Physics Engine will make collisions to absorb part of the force which moves your spinner, so unless you keep adding "artificial" forces to the spinner it will eventually stop.
- The "air friction" in your scene will also reduce the force of your
  spinner, so it will slow it down. You should add a material to the
  spinner which has 0 Dynamic Friction
- Based on the comment you left in @reymoss' answer, you may consider
  to add the bouncy material to the walls, and not to the spinning
  GameObject.

To sum up, the issue here is if you want a GameObject to bounce against a wall using the Physics Engine, the object will eventually stop, because some of the forces will be absorbed in each collision. That means you will need to keep adding external forces every time a collision takes place, to keep it moving endlessly.

Something you can try is,

1- Add a bouncy material to the walls and remove the dynamic friction of your spinner. In the following link you can learn about this:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html

2- Add to the Spinner a Collider, so when it detects a collision with a wall (you can tag the walls as so for example) add an additional force to the spinner in the direction it is already moving, so it will compensate the energy lost during the collision.

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
    if(other.tag == "wall") {
         rigidbody.AddForce(rigidbody.velocity.normalized * Time.deltaTime * forceAmount);    
    } 
}
```

The idea is to let the Engine decide the direction of the Spinner after the collision with the wall, and as soon as the GameObject leaves the trigger, you add an additional force in the current direction.

Then you can play with the `Bounciness` of the wall's material and with the `forceAmount`, until your spinner moves as you have in mind.

**Note**: Since you will have 2 materials, one in the walls and another in the spinner, maybe playing with the `Friction Combine` and `Bounce Combine` you will be able to avoid the force lost during collisions, so you will not need to add the external force I mention in the second step. However I have never tried this.

Let me know if it works. I can't try myself the solution until I arrive home.

Answer (score 2):

If you give the object an initial velocity, attach a collider, create and assign a Physics Material 2D to the collider ([to apply bounciness](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/PhysicsMaterial2DInspector.png)), and attach Colliders to the walls, you can have it bounce around with minimal code.

```
private void Start()
{
    rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rigid.velocity = new Vector3(2f, 3f, 1f) // initialize velocity here
}
```

Comment: I added a Physics Material to the spinner, with a bounciness of 1 and a bounce combine of maximum.

https://pastebin.com/h30QeBF1

   but the cube just starts to jump around instead of spinning.

The rigidbodies rotation on y is frozen.

Comment: what do you mean by "jump around"? can you be more specific? are you saying you have frozen the rotation on y? from your code it looks as though y is the only axis you want to rotate about, why are you freezing it?